# Write a query that will compare its results to the same results but with another date as reference

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting

I have a query that compares the final balance of a month with the final balance of the same month but from the year before.
The query works just fine, the issue is when I want to check against more than 2 years before, a query was made by my predecessor but this query takes too much time to print the results, it just adds another query per year of what we want to see, so the higher the year, the larger the query.

Another predecessor created a pivot table to see the results to present his information, only showing up to 3 years before, the query itself is good but when we want to display the whole information due to all the joins and unions the query becomes inefficient time-wise.

The project has been recently passed on to me, I see the original(structure/backbone) query looks good in order to achieve the results of the months final balance compared to last years monthly final balance, but I wish to make a more dynamic report regardless of the year/month we're looking into, and not just entirely hard coded or with repetition of the same query over and over again. But I've literally hit a wall since I can't come up with any idea of how to make it work in a more dynamic way. I'm fairly new to reporting and data analysis and that's basically what's limiting my progress.

```
    SELECT T2.[Segment_0]+'-'+T2.[Segment_1]+'-'+T2.[Segment_2] Cuenta,
    T2.[AcctName], SUM(T0.[Debit]) Debito, SUM(T0.[Credit]) Credito, 
    SUM(T0.[Debit])-SUM(T0.[Credit]) Saldo
    FROM  [server].[DB1].[dbo].[JDT1] T0  
    INNER  JOIN [server].[DB1].[dbo].[OJDT] T1  
    ON  T1.[TransId] = T0.[TransId] 
    INNER JOIN [server].[DB1].[dbo].[oact] T2
    ON T2.[AcctCode] = T0.[Account]
    WHERE T0.[RefDate] >= '2007-12-31'  AND  T0.[RefDate] <= '2016-06-30'  
    GROUP BY T2.[Segment_0]+'-'+T2.[Segment_1]+'-'+T2.[Segment_2],T2.[AcctName]
```

I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, but for someone who can point me and guide through the best possible course of action to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. It isn't clear to me why you need `[server].[DB1].[dbo].[OJDT] T1`. Its data doesn't appear in the output and it isn't needed to join `T0` to `T2`.  If you can omit it, do so.

   If you can't omit it because you need to exclude transactions from `T0` that aren't in `T1`, use an `EXISTS` clause rather than joining it in.
2. Use a CTE to group the `T0` records by `Account`, and then join the CTE to `T2`.  That way `T2` doesn't have to join to every record in `T0`, just the summarized result.  You also don't need to group by your composite field and your account name, because if you do your grouping in the CTE, they won't be grouped.

   Here's a sort of outline of what that would look like:

   ```
   ;
   WITH Summed as (
      SELECT  Account
          ,   SUM(Credito) as SumCredito
          ...
      FROM    [JDT1] T0
      WHERE   T0.[RefDate] >= ...
      GROUP BY Account
   )
   SELECT  (.. your composite segment field ..)
        ,  AccountName
        ,  SumCredito
   FROM    Summed T1
      JOIN [oact] T2
          ON T1.account = T2.acctcode
   ```
3. If you want dynamic dates, you will probably need to parameterize this and turn it into a stored proc if it isn't one already.
4. Push as much formatting (which includes pivoting already-grouped data from a list into a matrix) into the reporting tool as possible.  Achieving dynamic pivoting is tricky in T-SQL but trivial in SSRS, to pick just one tool.
5. Remember, you can always dynamically set the column headers in your tool: you don't have to change the column names in your data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Ann thank you so much for your answer, I have gone through the entire old report and now that I understand it much more I finally figured out what I want to do, I just don't know how, basically use the same query (old report had temp tables ugh) but I want to be able to search for multiple periods of time so basically I'm looking to adapt the `where refdate...` line.

Comment: Multiple periods as in "Jan-June 2014, Jan-June 2015, Jan-June 2016"?

Comment: Yes im currently working on a subquery seeing if that might workand the point of the report is to compare a month to the other same month but from previous years

Comment: Is there a way I could chat with you?  If that's possible

Comment: Yes, we can go to chat.stackoverflow.com.